# What Truncated polynomial mean in CRC16 CCITT context

Tags: c, crc16

Trying to understand [this](http://srecord.sourceforge.net/crc16-ccitt.html#overview) explanation of CRC16 CCITT, I came across to the term *"truncated polynomial"*. Comparing the long-hand calculation for a one-byte message with the corresponding C code, I found out that the macro definition of `poly` doesnt match the calculation example from the above. Into the C code the polynomial is `0x1021` while into the calculation example above the polynomial used is bigger, `0x11021`.

They use the term truncated polynomial for this: `0x1021`. What pattern do they use to extend this `0x1021` to this `0x11021`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x11021` represents polynomial `p = x^16+x^12+x^5+x^0` from F2[X]. Message (together with initial value and augmentation) is also represented by a polynomial. CRC is basically just message modulo polynomial `p`. Therefore CRC never needs more than 2 bytes. Since `p = 0 mod p` we can write `x^16 = x^12+x^5+x^0 mod p`. So `0x1021` represents `x^12+x^5+x^0`.

Now lets see how `update_good_crc` works:

```
void update_good_crc(unsigned short ch)
{
    unsigned short i, v, xor_flag;

    /*
    Align test bit with leftmost bit of the message byte.
    */
    v = 0x80;

    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        if (good_crc & 0x8000)
        {
            xor_flag= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            xor_flag= 0;
        }
        good_crc = good_crc << 1;

        if (ch & v)
        {
            /*
            Append next bit of message to end of CRC if it is not zero.
            The zero bit placed there by the shift above need not be
            changed if the next bit of the message is zero.
            */
            good_crc= good_crc + 1;
        }

        if (xor_flag)
        {
            good_crc = good_crc ^ poly;
        }

        /*
        Align test bit with next bit of the message byte.
        */
        v = v >> 1;
    }
}
```

1. This checks whether most significant bit of good_crc is set to zero. In other words, it checks whether coefficient at x^15  is set to 1 or 0.

   ```
   if (good_crc & 0x8000)
   {
       xor_flag= 1;
   }
   ```
2. `good_crc = good_crc << 1;` this multiplies good_crc by x. Thus coefficient at `x^15` becomes coefficient at `x^16` and good_crc "overflows" its 16 bits (that's why we stored xor_flag).
3. `good_crc = good_crc ^ poly;` if `xor_flag` is set then this "subtracts" `x^16 = x^12+x^5+x^0 mod p` from good_crc.

Comment: What do you mean saying `F2[X]`?
Why do they use `10001000000100001` as a polynomal when it is expicitly stated that the polynomial is `0001000000100001`? How come they appended the `1` infront? Where did this `1` came from? Moreover, into the `C` code I

Comment: @Hairi I mean polynomials in x such that all coefficients are just 0 or 1. I think that fancy name for that is polynomial ring.

Comment: ... they don't use this `0001000000100001` but this `10001000000100001` which is not `0x11021` but `0x1021`. I see difference into the polynomal representation in "Long Hand Calculation" and "The C Code"

Comment: @Hairi in this [document](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=275293) you can find that you should use polynomial represented by 10001000000100001. So this is the generator polynomial that generates error detection code. In C code they use 0x1021 because the first bit did not make it into 2 bytes and that's why the keep the value of most significant bit in xor_flag.